# Craft Cache Dependency with Redis

Tags: plugin-development, cache, yii

I am trying to make dependency's work using Craft Cache (set to Redis.)

I've tried:

```
craft()->cache->set('cache_key', 'cache_value', 0, new CFileCacheDependency('dependent_cache_key'));
```

This stores the cache. However, when I then update the value for cache with the key name `dependent_cache_key`, `cache_key` does not invalidate.

Is `CFileCacheDependency` not the right way to attach dependency to a cache key? All the YII description says is "File Name."

Also, is it possible to declare directories for Craft Cache? I see YII also has a dependency method for directories `CDirectoryCacheDependency`, which would be optimal in my case, but I have no idea how to assign a directory for cache using `craft()->cache->set()` and `craft->cache->get()`

Any help would be incredibly appreciated. Been stumped crawling through yii docs to figure this out.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/caching.data#cache-dependency